# Date in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

What am I doing wrong?

**This gives med 4 numbers**

```
d = new Date();
dag = d.getDate();
manad = d.getMonth();
manad++;
ar = d.getFullYear();

alert(ar+manad+dag);
```

**This gives me 8 numbers: the only difference is the ''+ in the alert message**

```
d = new Date();
dag = d.getDate();
manad = d.getMonth();
manad++;
ar = d.getFullYear();
alert('' + ar+manad+dag);
```

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UEy9h/1/

Comment: sorry! I see the problem now. Javascript reads it like 2011 + 11 + 14 = 2036... sorry I am getting tired... How are you supose to get the date in the format like this "20111114"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example it's doing a javascript add of the numbers together.  In the second example it's doing a concatenation because it thinks it's a string.

The output of the first example would be the day - 13, month - 11 then add 1, year = 2011 so it would be 13 +12 + 2011 = 2036

The second example would be 20111213, year - month + 1, day

Answer (score 0):

To get concatenation instead of addition, just put a string in the expression (an empty string will do):

```
alert('' + ar + manad + dag);
```